# WP Increase Panorama Overlap

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to create a windows phone landscape layout a below, but i can't get the overlap any further than the default setting.
I have tried to force it to by over stretching the next item but when i scroll to the next item it cuts it off, any ideas how to get this layout.

[image: What I'm Aiming For.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing from [panorama-item-to-be-full-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920375/how-to-modify-wp-panorama-item-to-be-full-screen).  We can modify it to use any margin you like.

```
public class PanoramaFullScreen : Panorama
{
    protected override System.Windows.Size MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size availableSize)
    {
        int _extraMargin = -150;                         // calculate how much you need
        availableSize.Width += _extraMargin;
        return base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);
    }
}
```

Then added the namespace of your project to the XAML so you can use your custom control.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:YOUR_NAME_SPACE">
```

Then you can use your Custom Panorama.

```
<custom:PanoramaFullScreen>
    <phone:PanoramaItem Header="One">
        <TextBlock Text="One"/>
    </phone:PanoramaItem>
    <phone:PanoramaItem Header="Two">
        <TextBlock Text="Two"/>
    </phone:PanoramaItem>
</custom:PanoramaFullScreen>
```